# datetutil has no attriubte tz when try to get the timezone

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to get  timezone using `dateutil.tz` [tz — dateutil 2.8.0 documentation](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html)

```
>>> import dateutil
>>> dateutil
<module 'dateutil' from '/home/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/__init__.py'>
>>> dateutil.tz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'dateutil' has no attribute 'tz'
```

It prompt that `dateutil`has no attribute `tz`

What's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried testing it outside of the anaconda environment (native python)? I would've liked to do it myself but unfortunately, I do not have the resources to do it until much later in the day

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package probably explains it. `import dateutil` does not import all resources within the containing directory. The presence of `__init__.py` merely allows the subdirectories to be treated as packages, but it does not load them by default. Apparently, we still have to load it explicitly either by `import dateutil.tz` or `from dateutil import *` - since `tz` is defined in the `__all__` variable

Answer (score 0):

`tz` is a sub module within the `dateutil` module which is why `dateutil.tz` will give you an error. Instead try this

`from dateutil import tz`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from dateutil import tz
>>> tz
<module 'dateutil.tz' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dateutil/tz.py'>
```

You need to import the dateutil submodules specifically.